# Shared hosting IP changed to https from http

Tags: https, http

I had a shared hosting on my service provider. Since last 6 months everything was going fine. But recently after some server problems, that halted services for many days and restored back, I am no longer able to access and test my files using http. I have to use https instead. With https, there is a known problem of certificate error on browser, that I want to avoid.

When I asked the customer support, they refused to help, saying that they cannot assure http for a shared hosting. And I must go for dedicated hosting. Or will need to purchase a domain name.

Before going to enquire any further, I wanted to know, if the customer support is giving the right information ?

Comment: I was hoping for a good response for you. I have no idea what to offer at this point other than changing hosts which may be a bit too extreme unless their tech support has really disappointed you. It seems to me that you have a valid concern that your host can help you solve. I had up-voted earlier hoping that would help get your question some attention. I hope you get some ideas soon. Cheers!!

Comment: known certificate error via https and support cannot assure http, sounds like the recipe for changing hosting providers.

Comment: Why are you getting browser errors for the cert? If it's something related to your end, and you're on XP, try using Firefox instead. It *may* work. If it's something related to their end, consider a different host ;)

Comment: Undoubtedly it's from their side. Yes, changing the host is the ultimate option.  But I did not expect this from a service provider like godaddy.. Also, changing the hosting means loosing all my remaining money I had invested in the plan which is  not refundable for the plan I opted for.